# How can I alter the window to which ctrl+w, ctrl+p will jump to?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, vim-windows, jump

What I'm looking for is a programmatic way of changing which window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> will jump to.

The reason why I want to do this is that I have an `autocmd` like the following

```
autocmd BufEnter  SpecialWindow call MyFunction()
```

where

```
function! MyFunction()
    let current_win_id = win_getid()
    windo ...
    call win_gotoid(current_win_id)
endfunction
```

therefore, as soon as I jump to the `SpecialWindow` from `AnotherWindow`, the meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is such that it does ***not*** jump to `AnotherWindow` (**desired behavior**), but it jumps to the bottom-right window, the last one visited by `windo`.

If you are interested in why I'm asking this question, please see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/239205/152455).

Comment: You mean `Ctrl-W Ctrl-P`?

Comment: @BLayer yes I do. I'll correct it later, or you can do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is for you to save what the previous window was before the `windo` command. Then, later, jump to that window before jumping to your target window.

```
function! MyFunction()
  let previous_win_id = win_getid(winnr('#'))
  let current_win_id = win_getid()
  windo ...
  call win_gotoid(previous_win_id)
  call win_gotoid(current_win_id)
endfunction
```

A better solution, though, is to use the [`win_execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#win_execute%28%29) function instead of the `windo` command. The `win_execute()` function prevents the side effects of entering a window while executing a command in that window, that includes updating the previous window (and the current window too.)

You need to use an explicit `for` loop to run the command on every window. You can use [`gettabinfo()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#gettabinfo%28%29) to find the window ids of the windows in the current tab.

```
function! MyFunction()
  for winid in gettabinfo(tabpagenr())[0]['windows']
    call win_execute(winid, '...')
  endfor
endfunction
```

If you want to iterate over every window in every tab, you can either use `gettabinfo()` with no arguments (to get info for all tabs) and two nested `for` loops (one for the list of tabs, then another one for the windows in that tab. Or you can use `getwininfo()` directly, which returns information for all windows in all tabs in a flattened list, so you need a single `for` loop.

If you're simply trying to set a variable or option in the other windows (e.g. disable `'relativenumber'`), then you can use [`setwinvar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setwinvar%28%29) for windows in the current tab, or [`settabwinvar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#settabwinvar%28%29) more generally.

For example, to disable the `'relativenumber'` in all windows of all tabs:

```
function! MyFunction()
  for tabinfo in gettabinfo()
    let tabnr = tabinfo['tabnr']
    for winid in tabinfo['windows']
      call settabwinvar(tabnr, winid, '&relativenumber', 0)
    endfor
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Wow! What a comprehensive answer! I'll get it tomorrow and accept.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Your question was very well formulated and also included the context and motivation, so thank you for that!

Comment: Hello, you might be interested in [this new question of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/does-a-plugin-exist-which-allows-moving-across-the-windows-and-split-them-with), which I tried to craft accurately.