# Does a plugin exist which allows moving (across) the windows and split them without having to press Ctrl+w before each action?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows, movement

I'm kind of fine with moving across windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> followed by (sometimes a counter and) <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, and I'm also fine with the similar key combinations to split the windows or to move or rotate them, but repeating the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> everytime is a bit annoying.

Therefore I was thinking of writing some mapping to create a kind of "move-across-windows pseudo-mode" which should make things easier. Specifically I was thinking of mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> such that it somehow

1. "hides" all the existing mappings and keys (I don't say un-mapping because that would require recovering all the mappings afterward),
2. maps those letters above to themselves preceded by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>,
3. maps the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to undo what is done in 1. and 2.

Before diving in, however, I'd like to know if a plugin already exists that allows something along these lines.

### I've written a plugin for this: [WinZoZ](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical ways to have sub modes:

- be in a buffer with dedicated `<buffer>` local mappings
- or enter a loop where we read key pressed and act accordingly.

The second point is more likely to correspond to what you're looking for:

1. enter the windows navigation mode
2. navigate
3. exit

It's implemented by waiting on `getchar()`. And we can even provide a dedicated status line. Here is an example I have in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/plugin/common_brackets.vim#L391):

```
if !hasmapto('BracketsManipMode')
    nnoremap <silent> <M-b>     :call BracketsManipMode("\<M-b>")<cr>
endif

function! BracketsManipMode(starting_key) " {{{
  redraw! " clear the msg line
  echohl StatusLineNC
  echo "\r-- brackets manipulation mode (x ( [ { < ' \" ` \\ <F1> q)"
  echohl None
  let key = getchar()
  let bracketsManip=nr2char(key)
  if (-1 != stridx("x".join(keys(s:k_pairs), '')."\\q",bracketsManip)) ||
        \ (key =~ "\\(\<F1>\\|\<Del>\\)")
    if     bracketsManip == "x"      || key == "\<Del>"
      call s:DeleteBrackets()    | redraw! | return ''
    elseif bracketsManip == "\\" | call s:ToggleBackslash()
    elseif has_key(s:k_pairs, bracketsManip)
      call s:ChangeTo(s:k_pairs[bracketsManip])
    elseif key == "\<F1>"
      redraw! " clear the msg line
      echo "\r *x* -- delete the current brackets pair\n"
      echo " *(* -- change the current brackets pair to round brackets ()\n"
      echo " *[* -- change the current brackets pair to square brackets []\n"
      echo " *{* -- change the current brackets pair to curly brackets {}\n"
      echo " *<* -- change the current brackets pair to angle brackets <>\n"
      echo " *'* -- change the current brackets pair to single quotes ''\n"
      echo " *\"* -- change the current brackets pair to double quotes \"\"\n"
      echo " *`* -- change the current brackets pair to back quotes ''\n"
      echo " *\\* -- toggle a backslash before the current brackets pair\n"
      echo " *q* -- quit the mode\n"
      continue
    elseif bracketsManip == "q"
      redraw! " clear the msg line
      return ''
      " else
    endif
    redraw! " clear the msg line
  else
    redraw! " clear the msg line
    return a:starting_key.bracketsManip
  endif
endfunction " }}}
```

Note: it deserved to be modernized: moved to an autoload plugin, annotated with `abort`...

Comment: I've created a small plugin for that. Would you like to review it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251269/vim-plugin-for-easy-window-navigation)?

Answer (score 2):

At one point I had mapped `<leader>w` to `<C-w>`, but I found I didn't like that (occasionally I use vim's that aren't configured like mine, and that habit made doing so annoying.)

I do have [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer) installed, though to be honest I rarely use it these days. You can setup a shortcut (`<C-e>` by default) to enter rezise mode, where `hjkl` resize windows. There is also a focus mode, where you switch windows, and a move mode, where you move them around. You typically have to "accept" or "deny" the changes after you've made them (`<enter>` or `q`/`<esc>`, though you can configure `<esc>` to accept instead). This only applies to resize mode, as far as I can tell, though it might not be hard to make it apply to the other modes, if you were in the mood to do so.

Comment: I believe https://github.com/tomtom/tinykeymap_vim https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2223 and https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2467 allow that

Comment: I've created a small plugin for that. Would you like to review it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251269/vim-plugin-for-easy-window-navigation)?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach is to set up `<Tab>` to jump from one window to the next.  If you don't have too many windows open, hitting `<Tab>` a few times is quicker than pretty much any other sequence of keys.

```
nnoremap <Tab> <C-W>w
nnoremap <S-Tab> <C-W>W
```

For when there are lots of windows, I use `<Leader>n`, where `n` is the window number (displayed in the status line), to jump directly to the desired window.  Add this to your vimrc to set it up:

```
for i in range(1, 9)
  execute 'nnoremap <Leader>'.i.' :'.i.'wincmd w<CR>'
endfor
```

And also `<Leader>0` to jump back to the previous window:

```
nnoremap <Leader>0 :wincmd p
```