# How do plugins work when providing several custom keys in a plugin-specific window?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-system

I'm referring to plugins like [gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) and [nerdtree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree), which offer a whole lot of key bindings only when the cursor is their window.

Therefore, I was wandering if there's a common or preferred way to accoplish something like this.

The intuitive way, to me, seems pretty obvious: create a `autocmd` that is triggered when the cursor moves into that window, and another one when it moves away from that windows. The two `autocmd`s should activate the plugin-specific mappings and revert the original mappings/functionalities respectively.

However, I can't see how the latter can be done without having to write a list of "mappings to be recovered or removed".

The motivation for this question is that I'm considering writing a small plugin to make all window-related actions (like moving them, moving across them, opening them, closing them, ...) easier to perform, as described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/does-a-plugin-exist-which-allows-moving-across-the-windows-and-split-them-with).

Comment: Isn't it simply with the `<buffer>` argument to `nnoremap` ? [`:h :map-local`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-local)

Comment: It seems like the plugins you refer to are doing this [here](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim/blob/master/autoload/gundo.vim#L113-L128) and [here](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/master/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim#L58). They are not *window*-specific but *buffer*-specific mappings.

Comment: @perelo, so it seems they only re-map what they need, without deactivate any other mapping or key for the sake of it, right? As in, if the plugin doesn't need to remap `j` to do something plugin-specific, then `j` will be left with its normal meaning, and not mapped to `<nop>`.

Comment: yes exactly. Global mappings are still available when buffer ones haven't overridden them. For your question, ie wriring *window*-specific mappings, you are right. I think we need to keep a list of current window mappings and use `WinEnter` and `WinLeave` to load and unload them.